# Button lossing click event after jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, transition

I have an issue that happpens only when I click fast on the button and I think it has to do something with the animations but I am not sure.

This is the DOM for side menu that slides out.

On the page there is a hamburger menu button. This button is responsible for initiating slide menu.

```
<a class="btn-hamburger btn-ripple btn-menu" href="#">
    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</a>
```

Somewhere in the DOM tree there is also slide out menu defained and in that menu as we can see we have pretty much the same button as the starting one.

```
<div class="side-menu-overlay hidden">
    <div class="side-menu">
        <div class="side-menu-header">
            <a class="btn-hamburger btn-ripple btn-menu" href="#">
                <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery that does the animation. As you can see from the DOM above, this event is fired for both the menu button at the start and the menu button in the slide out menu. Should the button slide out or side in depends on the class 'hidden' that is applied to overlay that hosts the slide out menu.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-menu', function (e) {
    if (sideMenuOverlay.hasClass('hidden')) {
        sideMenuOverlay.removeClass('hidden');
        sideMenuOverlay.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 200, function () {
            sideMenu.animate({
                 marginLeft: 0
            }, 250);
        });
    }
    else {
        sideMenu.animate({
            marginLeft: -240
        }, 200, function () {
            sideMenuOverlay.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 300, function () {
                sideMenuOverlay.addClass('hidden');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Problem that occurs is that the hamburger menu does not fire click events anymore. If I click the menu slowly with pauses in between, it will work all the time. As soon as I start clicking fast(to slide out and in fast) at one point the hamburger menu will not fire the event anymore. Funny enough it will always be the menu button at the start, so that means NOT when the overlay is visible and the menu is out.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem a bunch before and solution I have found to work is to use .stop() right in front of the .animate().

See this page: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

This will stop the animate queue from stacking events and getting hosed up.

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't work. It bafels me since the DOM doesn't change dynamicaly. Overlay as well as the slide menu are in the DOm tree from the begining. I also subscribed to document on click just in case but this is enigma for me. I even got rid of animation and just played with $.css instead and I got the same result. After multiple fast clicks I get no response. Debugger is not hitting the event.